# how do I test a facebook feed plugin on a website under development on localhost

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-test-users

I am building a website for a friend. I am using WordPress and doing the work on a localhost. My friend wants a Facebook feed. I have a plugin I like. I signed up as a test user on Facebook but because it's a test user and not a real user on a live site I can't get the plugin to work. I now understand that I am doing the wrong thing trying to use a test user Facebook page to give content to the plugin but I don't know what the right way is. Please tell me the correct way to use "dummy" Facebook content to test a Wordpress plugin on a non-live site. I will delete my test user as soon as I know the correct way. I'm working very hard to learn how to develop websites and how to correctly use Wordpress. I am also researching this on the Wordpress forum and on Google but I also need expert advice. Thank you.

Comment: For one, I hope you are referring to a Facebook Platform App test user (which you can create in the Facebook app settings), and not a fake user profile, because those tend to get deleted by Facebook. As to your question, please explain how you are implementing the feed plugin.

Comment: It's been so long since I posted this that I forgot I had it! I couldn't figure out a legal way to create "dummy" content, so I deleted my test user and made a Facebook page for myself and am testing the plugin with that. I will keep the page I made for myself as it pertains to the decorative artwork that I do. I may be new at website development, but I'm smart enough to know not **not** to create dummy accounts because they're nothing but trouble. Hope that explains how I'm implementing the feed plugin.

Comment: To the StackOverflow administrators: since it appears that this question is resolved, I suppose that you can mark it as such, or send it into the sewer of stupid noob questions. Thanks.

Comment: If you found a solution to your own question, you can answer it yourself and then mark the answer as "Accepted". That will make it clear that the issue is resolved.

Comment: **From the Help Center**  To encourage people to do this, there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a 
question. If you have _more than 15 reputation_ and already know the answer, click the checkbox that says "Answer your own question" at the bottom of the Ask Question page. Type in your answer, then submit both question and answer together. (_emphasis added_) I don't have a 15 reputation. I don't have a reputation, period. I don't have a checkbox, so I can't answer my own question. Now, please excuse me while I go find a place to cry and scream in frustration.